# If D is a ring with identity such that every unitary D-module is free, then D is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

This question is from my module theory assignment and I am struck on this particular problem.

> Prove that if D is a ring with identity such that every D-module is free, then D is a divison ring.

Attempt: To prove that D is Divison Ring it is sufficient to show that D has no proper ideals.
Let on the contrary D has a proper ideal I. Now , I have to somehow prove that some D-module is not free. But I am not able to get any ideas.

Can you please help?

Comment: If you know that $D$ has a proper ideal, what $D$-modules come to your mind?

Comment: Please search before asking. This was available in the Related questions to the right, and so it should have appeared when you were typing your original question in.